# Proof that the Change of Coordinates matrix methodology works

Tags: linear-algebra

We create a matric S which can convert a vector written as a coordinate vector from one basis to the other by representing each vector in basis B by basis C. (and then row reduce)...

However, what is the proof that this by multiplying [x]c = S[x]b actually works?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Please, restate it.

Comment: https://www.math.utah.edu/~honigs/changecoord.pdf

Comment: why does this work? I want a proof. (sorry my english is bad)

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathcal{B} = \{ \textbf{b}_1, \dots , \textbf{b}_n \}$ and $\mathcal{C} = \{ \textbf{c}_1, \dots , \textbf{c}_n \}$ be bases of a vector space $V$.

Let $P_{\mathcal{B}} = \big[ \textbf{b}_1 \dots \textbf{b}_n \big]$ be the  change-of-coordinates matrix from $\mathcal{B}$ to the standard basis.

Let $P_{\mathcal{C}} = \big[ \textbf{c}_1 \dots \textbf{c}_n \big]$ be the  change-of-coordinates matrix from $\mathcal{C}$ to the standard basis.

We see that
\begin{align}
P_{\mathcal{C}} \big[ \begin{matrix}[\textbf{b}_1]_{\mathcal{C}} &\dots & [\textbf{b}_n]_{\mathcal{C}} \end{matrix} \big] [\textbf{x}]_{\mathcal{B}}
 &= \big[ \begin{matrix} P_{\mathcal{C}} [\textbf{b}_1]_{\mathcal{C}} &\dots & P_{\mathcal{C}} [\textbf{b}_n]_{\mathcal{C}} \end{matrix} \big] [\textbf{x}]_{\mathcal{B}} \\
 &= \big[ \begin{matrix} \textbf{b}_1 &\dots & \textbf{b}_n \end{matrix} \big] [\textbf{x}]_{\mathcal{B}} \\
 &= P_{\mathcal{B}} [\textbf{x}]_{\mathcal{B}} \\
 &= \textbf{x},
\end{align}

so $\big[ \begin{matrix}[\textbf{b}_1]_{\mathcal{C}} &\dots & [\textbf{b}_n]_{\mathcal{C}} \end{matrix} \big] [\textbf{x}]_{\mathcal{B}} = [\textbf{x}]_{\mathcal{C}}$.